# Swap elements on drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working in Wordpress and I'm trying make it so when one of the draggable piece is dropped on the position of the other piece they swap places however every time I drop a piece nothing happens. Below there is the CSS part, the JS part and the html `part.Each` piece is a small picture with a hidden text also in div. If there's any more information needed please ask them freely.

```js
function dragWord(dragEvent) {
  dragEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", dragEvent.target.textContent + "|" + dragEvent.target.parentNode.id);
}

function dropWord(dropEvent) {
  var dropData = dropEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
  var dropItems = dropData.split("|");
  var prevElem = document.getElementById(dropItems[1]);
  prevElem.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].textContent = dropEvent.target.textContent;
  dropEvent.target.textContent = dropItems[0];
  dropEvent.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.right-sidebar .content-area {
  width: 98%;
}

.float-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.float-child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 0 14%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-container">
  <div id=1 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:100px; top:100px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_1.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/cum-id-fugiunt-re-eadem-defen/">Cum</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=2 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:200px; top:100px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_2.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/2.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/pauca-mutat-vel-plura-sane-lo/">Pau</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=3 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:300px; top:100px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_3.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/3.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/respondeat-totidem-verbis/">Res</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=4 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:400px; top:100px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_4.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/4.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/tum-mihi-piso-quid-ergo/">Tum</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=5 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:500px; top:100px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_5.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/5.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/neminem-videbis-ita-laudatum/">Nem</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=6 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:600px; top:100px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_6.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/6.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/sin-laboramus-quis-est-qui-a/">Sin</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=7 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:700px; top:100px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_7.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/7.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/et-harum-quidem-rerum-facilis-est/">Et </a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=8 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:100px; top:200px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_8.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/8.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/nullus-est-igitur-cuiusquam-dies-n/">Nul</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=9 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:200px; top:200px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_9.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/9.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/huius-lyco-oratione-locuples/">Hui</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=1 0 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:300px; top:200px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_10.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/10.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/duo-reges-constructio-interre/">Duo</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=1 1 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:400px; top:200px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_11.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/11.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/quaesita-enim-virtus-est/">Qua</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=1 2 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:500px; top:200px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_12.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/12.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/idemne-potest-esse-dies-saepius/">Ide</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=1 3 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:600px; top:200px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_13.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/13.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/hunc-vos-beatum-lorem-ipsum-do/">Hun</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=1 4 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:700px; top:200px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_14.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/14.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/nam-quibus-rebus-efficiunt/">Nam</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=1 5 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:100px; top:300px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_15.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/15.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/nunc-haec-primum-fortasse-audie/">Nun</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=1 6 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:200px; top:300px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_16.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/16.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/me-igitur-ipsum-ames-oporte/">Me </a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=1 7 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:300px; top:300px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_17.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/17.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/test1/">tes</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=1 8 class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)" style=" left:400px; top:300px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%;height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_18.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/18.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragWord(event)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/hello-world/">Hel</a></h3>
  </div>

  <!--<br> -->



  <div id=1 9 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:500px; top:300px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_19.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/19.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/quamquam-id-quidem-licebit-iis/">Qua</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=2 0 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:600px; top:300px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_20.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/20.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/hanc-quoque-iucunditatem-si-vis/">Han</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=2 1 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:700px; top:300px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_21.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/21.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/praetereo-multos-in-bis-doc/">Pra</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=2 2 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:100px; top:400px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_22.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/22.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/negat-enim-summo-bono-afferre-in/">Neg</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=2 3 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:200px; top:400px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_23.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/23.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/at-miser-si-in-flagitiosa-et/">At </a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=2 4 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:300px; top:400px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_24.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/24.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/omnes-enim-iucundum-motum-qu/">Omn</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=2 5 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:400px; top:400px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_25.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/25.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/nam-si-amitti-vita-beata-pote/">Nam</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=2 6 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:500px; top:400px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_26.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/26.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/transfer-idem-ad-modestiam-vel/">Tra</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=2 7 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:600px; top:400px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_27.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/27.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/sed-nimis-multa-lorem-ip/">Sed</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=2 8 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:700px; top:400px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_28.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/28.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/quae-fere-omnia-appellantur-uno/">Qua</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=2 9 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:100px; top:500px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_29.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/29.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/et-ais-si-una-littera-comm/">Et </a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=3 0 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:200px; top:500px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_30.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/30.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/quamquam-in-hac-divisione-rem/">Qua</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=3 1 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:300px; top:500px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_31.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/31.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/illa-tamen-simplicia-vestra/">Ill</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=3 2 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:400px; top:500px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_32.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/32.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/nihil-illinc-huc-pervenit/">Nih</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=3 3 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:500px; top:500px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_33.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/33.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/itaque-ab-his-ordiamur-l/">Ita</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=3 4 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:600px; top:500px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_34.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/34.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/proizvod2/">pro</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
  <div id=3 5 class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)" style=" left:700px; top:500px">
    <img style="object-fit: cover;width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/pocetna_35.jpg" alt="http://vjezbanje.local/wp-content/themes/storefront/img/35.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="ondragstart(e)">
    <h3 style="display: none;"><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/product/proizvod1/">pro</a></h3>
  </div>
  <!--<br> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us the functions you are calling on those two events? (drop and allowDrop)

Comment: oh sorry that's my bad, it's something i forgot to remove, i'll edit it out but it doesn't change anything i just tired it

Comment: Don't use inline `style=""` attributes! CSS should be in one place only, and that's the respective tag or file. Same goes for `on*=""` attributes.

Comment: `<div id=1 9 ` are invalid IDs - Also, why are you not consistent with your attributes? Half of your example use `class="float-child" ondragover="event.preventDefault()" ondrop="dropWord(event)"` and the other half uses `class="float-child" ondragover="ondragover(e)" ondrop="ondrop(e)"` and as you can tell you don't have ever specified and defined those functions `ondragover` etc in your JS code.

Answer (score 3):

- Don't use [inline `on*` JS handlers attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these).
  JS should be in one place only and that's its respective `<script>` tag or file.
- Always use [ąddEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to cumulatively add Event listeners - (use `on*` Event handlers only if you're creating a brand new Element from in-memory in JavaScript)
- Don't use inline `style` attributes.
  CSS should be in one place only and that's its respective `<style>` tag or file.
- You don't need IDs.
- **Swap your elements using [cloneNode(true)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) and [replaceWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith)**
- Create a function that will ease reassigning your Events on a fresh or cloned element like `addEvents()` in the below example:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const ELS = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);


// TASK:

const ELS_child = ELS(".float-child");

let EL_drag; // Used to remember the dragged element

const addEvents = (EL_ev) => {
  EL_ev.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
  EL_ev.addEventListener("dragstart", onstart);
  EL_ev.addEventListener("dragover", (ev) => ev.preventDefault());
  EL_ev.addEventListener("drop", ondrop);
};

const onstart = (ev) => EL_drag = ev.currentTarget;

const ondrop = (ev) => {
  if (!EL_drag) return;

  ev.preventDefault();
  
  const EL_targ = ev.currentTarget;
  const EL_targClone = EL_targ.cloneNode(true);
  const EL_dragClone = EL_drag.cloneNode(true);
  
  EL_targ.replaceWith(EL_dragClone);
  EL_drag.replaceWith(EL_targClone);
  
  addEvents(EL_targClone); // Reassign events to cloned element
  addEvents(EL_dragClone); // Reassign events to cloned element
  
  EL_drag = undefined;
};

ELS_child.forEach((EL_child) => addEvents(EL_child));
```

```css
/* QuickReset */ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.float-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.float-child {
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1 0 14%;
  width: 100px;
}

.float-child img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-container">
  <div class="float-child">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/224e5f/FFFFFF/png" alt="icon">
    <h3><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/cum-id-fugiunt-re-eadem-defen/">Cum</a></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="float-child">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/404a2a/FFFFFF/png" alt="icon">
    <h3><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/pauca-mutat-vel-plura-sane-lo/">Pau</a></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="float-child">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/9995fd/FFFFFF/png" alt="icon">
    <h3><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/respondeat-totidem-verbis/">Res</a></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="float-child">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/1cd279/FFFFFF/png" alt="icon">
    <h3><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/tum-mihi-piso-quid-ergo/">Tum</a></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="float-child">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/fffb43/FFFFFF/png" alt="icon">
    <h3><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/neminem-videbis-ita-laudatum/">Nem</a></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="float-child">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/811f50/FFFFFF/png" alt="icon">
    <h3><a href="http://vjezbanje.local/sin-laboramus-quis-est-qui-a/">Sin</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't cloneNode your elements just to swap them, simply use a temporary node: https://jsfiddle.net/vmr9q4o0/

Comment: thank you this helped me a lot i still need to solve few minor things but this helped me move on.